# get JSON data at click a button using promises

Tags: json, angular, angular5, angular-promise

I'm receiving JSON data using promises and it works. But now I want to implement a button who call again API (any time that you call API you get different values) how can I do it?

quotes-provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Quote } from './quote.model';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { resolve } from "path";
import { reject } from "q";

@Injectable()
export class QuotesProvider {
    private quote: Quote;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public getQuote(): Quote {
        return this.quote;
    }

    load() {
        console.log("loading data...");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http
                .get('http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.quote = response;
                    console.log("loading complete");
                    resolve(true);
                })
        })
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { QuoteBoxComponent } from './quote-box/quote-box.component';

import { QuotesProvider } from './quote-box/quotes-provider';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

export function quotesProviderFactory(provider: QuotesProvider) {
  return () => provider.load();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QuoteBoxComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    QuotesProvider,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: quotesProviderFactory, deps: [QuotesProvider], multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

quote-box.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-quote-box',
  templateUrl: './quote-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quote-box.component.css']
})
export class QuoteBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  // @HostBinding('class.quote-box') quoteBox = true;
  // http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json
  quote: Quote;

  constructor(public quotesProvider: QuotesProvider) {
    this.quote = quotesProvider.getQuote();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.quote.author);
  }

  // here I want to call API again
  newQuote() {
  }
}
```

I'm following this tutorial to do this https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/

Comment: You can use < button (click)="quotesProvider.getQuote()">click</button> But I don't know why you want use Promise and not Observables -any way, I don't understand becase you use a "deprecated" http anf not use httpClient (see https://angular.io/guide/http)- and why not use ngOnInit to do the request

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you want to do but if i understeand it right I dont know why are u doing this in that way. I would just create service and then inject to your components and use it on button click. Maybe tutorial is a little bit outdated.

quotes.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class QuotesService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getQuotes() {
    return this.http.get('http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json', 
    httpOptions);
  }

}
```

Then in your component in method called on button click

Constructor

```
constructor(private quotesService : QuotesService) { }
```

In method called on button click

```
this.quotesService.getQuotes().subscribe(quotes => {

     // do what you want with your qoutes
    });
```